# QuickSort vs MergeSort, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, performance, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I am trying to implement several sorting algorithms in Java, to compare the performances. From what I've read, I was expecting quickSort to be faster than mergeSort, but on my code it is not, so I assume there must be a problem with my quickSort algorithm:

```
public class quickSortExample{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Random gen = new Random();
    int n = 1000000;
    int max = 1500000;
    ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        d.add(gen.nextInt(max));
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> r;
    long start, end;

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    r = quickSort(d);
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("QuickSort:");
    System.out.println("Time: " + (end-start));
    //System.out.println(display(d));
    //System.out.println(display(r));
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> data){
    if(data.size() > 1){
        int pivotIndex = getPivotIndex(data);
        int pivot = data.get(pivotIndex);
        data.remove(pivotIndex);
        ArrayList<Integer> smallers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> largers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
            if(data.get(i) <= pivot){
                smallers.add(data.get(i));
            }else{
                largers.add(data.get(i));
            }
        }
        smallers = quickSort(smallers);
        largers = quickSort(largers);
        return concat(smallers, pivot, largers);
    }else{
        return data;
    }
}

public static int getPivotIndex(ArrayList<Integer> d){
    return (int)Math.floor(d.size()/2.0);
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> concat(ArrayList<Integer> s, int p, ArrayList<Integer> l){
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(s);
    arr.add(p);
    arr.addAll(l);

    return arr;
}

public static String display(ArrayList<Integer> data){
    String s = "[";
    for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++){
        s += data.get(i) + ", ";
    }
    return (s+"]");
}

}
```

Results (on 1 million integer between 0 and 1500000):

mergeSort (implemented with arrayList too): 1.3sec (average) (0.7sec with int[] instead)

quickSort: 3sec (average)

Is it just the choice of my pivot which is bad, or are there some flaws in the algo too.

Also, is there a faster way to code it with int[] instead of ArrayList()? (How do you declare the size of the array for largers/smallers arrays?)

PS: I now it is possible to implement it in an inplace manner so it uses less memory, but this is not the point of this.

EDIT 1: I earned 1 sec by changing the concat method.
Thanks!

Comment: First question: Do they both actually work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PS: I now it is possible to implement it in an inplace manner so it uses less memory, but this is not the point of this.

It's not just to use less memory.  All that extra work you do in the "concat" routine instead of doing a proper in-place QuickSort is almost certainly what's costing so much. If you can use extra space anyway, you should always code up a merge sort because it'll tend to do fewer comparisons than a QuickSort will.

Think about it: in "concat()" you inevitably have to make another pass over the sub-lists, doing more comparisons. If you did the interchange in-place, all in a single array, then once you've made the decision to interchange two places, you don't make the decision again.

Answer (score 2):

I think the major problem with your quicksort, like you say, is that it's not done in place.

The two main culprits are `smallers` and `largers`. The default size for an ArrayList is 10. In the initial call to quickSort a good pivot will mean that smallers and largers grow to 500,000. Since the ArrayList only doubles in size when it reaches capacity, it will have to be resized at around 19 times.

Since you are make a new smaller and larger with each level of recursion your going to be performing approximately 2*(19+18+...+2+1) resizes. That's around 400 resizes the ArrayList objects have to perform before they are even concatenated. The concatenation process will probably perform a similar number of resizes.

All in all, this is a lot of extra work.

Oops, just noticed `data.remove(pivotIndex)`. The chosen pivot index (middle of the array) is also going to be causing additional memory operations (even though middle is usual a better choice than beginning or end or the array). That is arraylist will copy the entire block of memory to the 'right' of the pivot one step to the left in the backing array.

A quick note on the chosen pivot, since the integers you are sorting are evenly distributed between n and 0 (if `Random` lives up to its name), you can use this to choose good pivots. That is, the first level of quick sort should choose max*0.5 as its pivot. The second level with smallers should choose max*0.25 and the second level with largers should choose max*0.75 (and so on).

Answer (score 1):

I think, that your algo is quite inefficient because you're using intermediate arrays = more memory + more time for allocation/copy. Here is the code in C++ but the idea is the same: you have to swap the items, and not copy them to another arrays

```
template<class T> void quickSortR(T* a, long N) {

  long i = 0, j = N;        
  T temp, p;

  p = a[ N/2 ];     


  do {
    while ( a[i] < p ) i++;
    while ( a[j] > p ) j--;

    if (i <= j) {
      temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = temp;
      i++; j--;
    }
  } while ( i<=j );



  if ( j > 0 ) quickSortR(a, j);
  if ( N > i ) quickSortR(a+i, N-i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fundamentals of OOP and data structures in Java By Richard Wiener, Lewis J. Pinson](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dJ_DXvFnIgoC&lpg=PP1&ots=inPYxWVTBX&dq=fundamentals%20of%20oop%20and%20data%20structures%20in%20java&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) lists quicksort as following, which may or may not be faster (I suspect it is) than your implementation...

```
public static void quickSort (Comparable[] data, int low, int high) {
    int partitionIndex;
    if (high - low > 0) {
        partitionIndex = partition(data, low, high);
        quickSort(data, low, partitionIndex - 1);
        quickSort(data, partitionIndex + 1, high);
    }
}

private static int partition (Comparable[] data, int low, int high) {
    int k, j;
    Comparable temp, p;
    p = data[low]; // Partition element
    // Find partition index(j).
    k = low;
    j = high + 1;

    do {
        k++;
    } while (data[k].compareTo(p) <= 0 && k < high);

    do {
        j--;
    } while (data[j].compareTo(p) > 0);

    while (k < j) {
        temp = data[k];
        data[k] = data[j];
        data[j] = temp;

        do {
            k++;
        } while (data[k].compareTo(p) <= 0);

        do {
            j--;
        } while (data[j].compareTo(p) > 0);
    }
    // Move partition element(p) to partition index(j).
    if (low != j) {
        temp = data[low];
        data[low] = data[j];
        data[j] = temp;
    }
    return j; // Partition index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the reason is unnecessary copying. Some more notes follow.

The choice of pivot index is bad, but it's not an issue here, because your numbers are random.

`(int)Math.floor(d.size()/2.0)` is equivalent to `d.size()/2`.

`data.remove(pivotIndex);` is unnecessary copying of `n/2` elements. Instead, you should check in the following loop whether `i == pivotIndex` and skip this element. (Well, what you *really* need to do is inplace sort, but I'm just suggesting straightforward improvements.)

Putting all elements that are equal to pivot in the same ('smaller') part is a bad idea. Imagine what happens when all elements of the array are equal. (Again, not an issue in this case.)

```
for(i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
    arr.add(s.get(i));
}
```

is equivalent to `arr.addAll(s)`. And of course, unnecessary copying here again. You could just add all elements from the right part to the left one instead of creating new list.

> (How do you declare the size of the array for largers/smallers arrays?)

I'm not sure if I got you right, but do you want `array.length`?

So, I think that even without implementing in-place sort you can significantly improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Mergesort has a better time-behavior ( **Θ(nlogn)** worst and average cases ) than Quicksort ( **Θ(n^2)** worst case, **Θ(nlogn)** average case). So it is quite possible to find inputs for which Mergesort outperforms Quicksort. Depending on how you pick your pivots, you can make the worst-case rare. But for a simple version of Quicksort, the "worst case" will be sorted (or nearly sorted) data, which can be a rather common input.

[Here's what Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) about the two:

> On typical modern architectures,
>   efficient quicksort implementations
>   generally outperform mergesort for
>   sorting RAM-based arrays. On the other
>   hand, merge sort is a stable sort,
>   parallelizes better, and is more
>   efficient at handling slow-to-access
>   sequential media.[citation needed]
>   Merge sort is often the best choice
>   for sorting a linked list: in this
>   situation it is relatively easy to
>   implement a merge sort in such a way
>   that it requires only Θ(1) extra
>   space, and the slow random-access
>   performance of a linked list makes
>   some other algorithms (such as
>   quicksort) perform poorly, and others
>   (such as heapsort) completely
>   impossible.